# C# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to list / add item to array

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to add a item to a array. But I think a list would be way easier since I could use

```
list.Add("whatever");
```

Is there a way to receive the following as a list?

```
dynamic reps = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("rep.json");
```

Example json:

```
{"reps": {
    {
        "username": "usera",
        "reps": 10,
        "latestrep": "userx"
    },
    "userb": { 
        "username": "userb",
        "reps": 10,
        "latestrep": "userx"
    },
    "userc": {
        "username": "userc",
        "reps": 10,
        "latestrep": "userx"
    }
}}
```

I appreciate any kind of help

Comment: Please show a relevant snippet of your JSON.

Comment: added a example

Comment: That's invalid, pretty sure you've missed some out

Comment: Is that really how your data is modelled? Do you have any control over the source? It looks like your users should be an array of user objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing you have a class defining the list item:

```
public class UserReps
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int Reps { get; set; }
    public string LatestRep { get; set; }
}
```

You can achieve what you want with LINQ:

```
IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, UserReps>> parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, UserReps>>>(json);
List<UserReps> userReps = parsed["reps"].Select(ur => ur.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

`

```
public static dynamic FromJsonToDynamic(this object value)
        {
            dynamic result = value.ToString().FromJsonToDynamic();
            return result;
        }
```

`

That is an extension method that I use for generic objects.  If you are looking at something to convert it to a particular object you could create an extension method like this:

```
public static T FromJson<T>(this object value) where T : class
    {
        T result = value.ToString().FromJson<T>();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

With your data as it is at the moment, no. Your input data doesnt appear to be a collection or something that could logically be 'listified'.